# Why does System.Convert has ToDateTime that accepts DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, converters

```
//
// Summary:
//     Returns the specified System.DateTime object; no actual conversion is performed.
//
// Parameters:
//   value:
//     A date and time value.
//
// Returns:
//     value is returned unchanged.
public static DateTime ToDateTime(DateTime value);
```

Why does `System.Convert` has `ToDateTime` that accepts DateTime ?

The method documentation states the value remain unchanged.

Comment: I could imagine to maintain consistency, especially for reflection. Imagine you are using the `Convert` class to convert some `object` to a `DateTime`; you don't know its input type. It can be a few different types _including_ `DateTime`, but rather than check for that special case, the BCL designers decided to keep that method there for consistency rather than have it throw exceptions. This can be seen with the other types too (e.g., `Convert.ToDouble(double)`)

Comment: It's not an isolated case. Practically all of the `ToXXX` methods for the simple built in types have an overload that accepts a value of that same type.

Comment: Also there is a method called [`String.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tc6ws5s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by the way `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convention, predictability and because the [`IConvertable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) defines the method `ToDateTime`.

I believe that under the covers, `System.Convert` simply runs through all the combinations of the `IConvertable` classes.

Comment: actually System.Convert in To.. methods has two options to do: 1. cast specified value to IConvertible interface and call apropriated method, i.e. ToDateTime. 2. call <type convert value to>.Parse for string passed to a method.

Answer (score 2):

The actual code is indeed:

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(DateTime value)
{
  return value;
}
```

This confirms the value will be unmodified.
There are a lot of convert methods. I think it is there just because it should accept all primitive objects in the signatures.

I.e. when using reflection, if would be unexpected if a convert from a `DateTime` to `DateTime` is not supported.