# Why does DateTime.ToDateTime( ) not compile?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306667/why-does-system-convert-has-todatetime-that-accepts-datetime) which I tried and failed to explain in my answer.

DateTime implements [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can prove this because

```
IConvertible dt = new DateTime();
```

compiles without an issue.

You can write the following code and there are no compile errors

```
IConvertible dt = new DateTime();
dt.ToDateTime(val);
```

However if you write the next code fragment it doesn't compile

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt.ToDateTime(val);
```

> 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'ToDateTime'

If DateTime implements the interface why can you not call the method on a DateTime unless it's cast to an IConvertible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `DateTime` implements `IConvertible` interface explicitly - this method is listed in [Explicit Interface Implementations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) section on MSDN. And here is how it implemented:

```
DateTime IConvertible.ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
{
    return this;
}
```

You should cast `DateTime` to `IConvertible`:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
var result = ((IConvertible)dt).ToDateTime(val);
```

See [Explicit Interface Implementation (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx)