# Why does System.Convert() provide implementation of not supported conversions?

Tags: c#, .net

**MS Documentation:**

ToDateTime(Object)
Converts the value of the specified object to a DateTime object.

ToDateTime(Double)
Calling this method always throws InvalidCastException.

ToDateTime(Int32)
Calling this method always throws InvalidCastException.

ToDateTime(Int16)
Calling this method always throws InvalidCastException.

ToDateTime(Int64)
Calling this method always throws InvalidCastException.

ToDateTime(Decimal)
Calling this method always throws InvalidCastException.

Why providing such methods?

**MS Source code (including comments):**

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs

At the beginning is a matrix describing which conversions are supported and which are not:

```
    // From:  To: Bol Chr SBy Byt I16 U16 I32 U32 I64 U64 Sgl Dbl Dec Dat Str
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Boolean     x       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
    // Char            x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x                   x
    // SByte       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
    // Byte        x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
    // Int16       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
    // UInt16      x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
    // Int32       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
    // UInt32      x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
    // Int64       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
    // UInt64      x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
    // Single      x       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
    // Double      x       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
    // Decimal     x       x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x       x
    // DateTime                                                        x   x
    // String      x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Each 'x' stands for a supported conversion. But for the blanks " " (not supported versions) there are methods too, e.g.

```
        public static DateTime ToDateTime(byte value) {
            return ((IConvertible)value).ToDateTime(null);
        }
```

See also similar question:
[Why does System.Convert has ToDateTime that accepts DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306667/why-does-system-convert-has-todatetime-that-accepts-datetime)

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to answer this question. My personal opinion is that it was a design error on the behalf of Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

Because any other option – given user defined (value) types – is more complicated. This is even more so when there is no generics (as was the case when these types were defined).

Compare .NET 7/C# 11 with static members of (generic) interfaces like [`IParsable<TSelf>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iparsable-1?view=net-7.0) potentially will still throw (or fail) at runtime because anything can be passed when using methods that take an `Object`.

Alternately you could force all possible data types to only be defined at compile time, which is fine until you need to pass data to/from other programs and users which are imperfect.

Comment: I would think its because of this comment in the source: "The set of conversions is symmetric such that for every ToXXX(YYY) there is also a ToYYY(XXX)."

Comment: I don't see why they needed to add (for example) the static methods `Convert.ToDateTime(Int32)` and `Convert.ToInt32(DateTime)`. Both those methods will throw if called - but they could both have been omitted from the original design of `Convert` without loss of functionality. Is this actually just a leaky implementation detail?

Comment: @MatthewWatson could you not say the same thing for all other cases except for String and DateTime? It to me is purely just for the symmetry of the class.

Comment: @TimothyG. That's a completely useless reason to include such methods though. And excluding both of them wouldn't break the symmetry either. If there isn't a `ToDateTime(Int32)` then you don't need a `ToInt32(DateTime)` according to the quoted comment.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I agree it's useless - but that is how they designed it I suppose.  Also, is there not a [`ToDateTime(Int32)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1754) or am I wrong? Also a [`ToInt32(DateTime)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1124)?

Comment: Having all the methods means an implementer of `IConvertible` can delegate most cases – even when expected to fail – to the static methods of `Converter` (DRY). When these methods were defined (over 20 years ago) .NET was very different... the reasoning then would not today justify their inclusion (IMHO) .

Comment: @Richard You can see [an example in the documentation for `IConvertable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=net-6.0), and for the implementation of `DateTime IConvertible.ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)` it's explicitly calling `return Convert.ToDateTime(GetDoubleValue());` which is just a convoluted way of throwing `InvalidCastException`... It would have been much better if Microsoft omitted those methods so you couldn't call them and you would have to explicitly put the `throw` in the implementation!

Comment: @TimothyG. "Also, is there not a ToDateTime(Int32) or am I wrong? Also a ToInt32(DateTime)" Yes, and I'm saying that NEITHER of those should exist, they are useless and only serve to give a programmer rope with which to hang themselves...

Comment: @MatthewWatson I see your point now. And again,  totally useless. But like Richard said, this code was written when things were "different", so the useless code is pretty much just that. Be cool to see what the original developers would say on this, but if I had to guess, it was purely for the symmetry, as useless as it is.